# Is there a way to get all "liked" (heart) images from a shared google photos album

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I have a shared Google Photos album with thousands of images where several people marked which images they liked using the heart button. I want to collect all of these images, but I don't see any way to do it other than going through each image manually. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

I'm also interested in getting all of the images that X people liked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you click a photo to enlarge a photo in the Shared album, you will see a tiny speech bubble in the lower left corner. Click this speech bubble, and you will see a special info panel with the "Like". You will see the likes in the "Activity" album in the Shared section of the albums

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that option but this is manual one image at a time. I was looking for something automatic that will gather all these images to a new selected images album